# QProcess ReadAllStandardError()

Tags: qt, qprocess

I need to connect a QProcess to an error handler, but I'm unsure how to pass the error string to the slot.  What's below compiles, but doesn't work.

```
QString MainWindow::RunProcess(QString cstring)
{
 QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
 connect(process,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),this,SLOT( adberror(process::ReadAllStandardError() ) ))
 process->start(cstring);    
}



void MainWindow::adberror(QString errtxt)
{  
  qDebug() << "error handler"; 
  qDebug() << errtxt;
 }
```

I can induce a a process error, but adberror() never triggers.

When run, in the Application Output pane I see:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::adberror(process::ReadAllStandardError() )
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

edit: this is Qt 5.6.  I did a new qmake/clean.

Comment: first, your signal and slot args have to match .. second, ReadAllStandardError is not going to be ready anyways !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options

1- wait before reading the output

```
QString MainWindow::RunProcess(QString cstring)
{
  QProcess process;
  process.start(cstring);
  process.waitForFinished();
  QString str = process.readAllStandardOutput();
}
```

2- make you `process` a member variable and remove your 1st argument from `adberror`. So,

in `RunProcess`

```
connect(process,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),this,SLOT(adberror()))
```

then in `adberror`

```
QString str = process->readAllStandardOutput();
```

note that in your code you have a problem since your signal and slot args don't to match .. Also, `ReadAllStandardError` is not going to be ready anyways !

**Edit: more code for the 2nd solution**

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow
{
   private://methods
      void adberror();

   private://attributes
      QProcess* process;

};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
QString MainWindow::RunProcess(QString cstring)
{
   process = new QProcess(this);
   connect(process,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),this,SLOT(adberror()));   
   connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), process, SLOT(deleteLater())); 
   process->start(cstring);    
}

void MainWindow::adberror()
{  
   QString str = process->readAllStandardOutput();
   qDebug() << str;
}
```

Comment: process->readAllStandardOutput(); fails on compile, adberror() doesn't know what it is.

Comment: @Alan that's why in my answer I mentioned that you need to make **process a member variable** of MainWindow

Comment: Thanks HG. I'd appreciate it if you could explain how that's done. As I mentioned above I can add "QProcess process;" in my mainwindow.cpp prior to MainWindow::MainWindow." and it works, but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: @Alan I added more details for the 2nd solution. you should consider the 1st solution first since it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

To process the `readyReadStandardError()` signal you should define the slot as:

```
private slots:
  void adberror();
```

and use it:

```
connect(process,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),this,SLOT( adberror() ));
```

i.e. with no arguments. Keep child process as a field of your `MainWindow` class to read data when it will be available.

Comment: What do you mean by "Keep child process as a field of your MainWindow class" ?  I can add "QProcess process;"  prior to MainWindow::MainWindow..., and it works, but I don't think that is what you're suggesting is a global. Very noob, sorry.

Comment: @Alan To get more information about field members and other C++ `class` features read ["Class declaration"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) specification. The most interesting part for you is *Member specification*.